# Django memory leak after network disconnected?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The question is Django 2.2 DRF 3.8.2 DB postgres
When the connection is disconnected after a REST request, the RAM is not cleared.
That is, data from the database is unloaded and remains in RAM, somewhere deep in Django.
How can such a problem be overcome ?

Comment: Could you provide an analysis of why you think that is a memory leak?

Comment: after the request and disconnection of the connection , the allocated RAM remains occupied , if you repeat the request and disconnect , then the memory is allocated even more and is not released until the server crashes

Comment: Are you using any custom CACHES backend?

Comment: Yes cach is custom. redis. But ,i try use default cache not result

Comment: Then you need to post your settings.py and other settings related to redis. It could be a configuration problem.

Comment: I'm not ready to post settings right now, I'll try to do it in the evening, thank you

Comment: Is the DEBUG setting enabled ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG

Comment: in settings.py DEBUG False